# Time dimension support for GeoServer layer groups

Tags: geoserver, wms, geowebcache

I have a couple of NetCDF layers for which time dimension is enabled in GeoServer. However, I want to use them in a Layer Group together with layers without time dimension.

Ultimately, I would like to generate GWC cache for each time step of the layer group.

I can't find anything about layer dimensions in layer groups. Is this supported in GeoServer?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not, as of version 2.23.x.

Dimension enabling a layer group could prove to be challenging in general, there is no guarantee the dimensions of the layers making up the group would align.

Comment: ok, thanks for confirmation. I'm making the layers and groups programatically, hence I'm sure that the dimensions align, so didn't think of this inconvenience.